# Android button opens random link from list

Tags: android

I'm creating a app that will open a random link in the browser from my list, however I am not sure on how to implement it, and I can only find examples in Javascript.
Here is my code so far :

```
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);


        }

    });
```

As you can see, I got the button itself down, however, how would I make it extract a link at random from a list that I have created.I appreciate any answers or attempts at helping. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a list containing all the links. What you can do is generate a random int position using Random class like -

```
Random rand = new Random();
randomNum = minimum + rand.nextInt((maximum - minimum) + 1);
```

Here minimum will be 0 & maximum will be your size of list. So by doing this we will generate a random position within the range of your list.
After getting the position we can just do

```
`list.get(randomNum)`
```

which will give you random links based on position.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(getRandomLink());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);


    }

});


private String getRandomLink(){
String[] list = {};//List of url
Random r = new Random();
list[r.nextInt(list.length)];

}
```